# Making enquiries about shares

Tags: stocks, india, family

My father had bought shares in 1999. I do not have any physical record of this, as they are held by one of my father's friends, who is not available right now. Is anything possible, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you need the physical shares for? What does the "expense-ratio" tag have to do with anything?

Comment: You need to find out what brokerage they were purchased with... and then speak with them about it. It's fairly rare to have actual paper printed shares now-days.

Comment: Who actually bought the shares?  In other words, who is listed as the shareholder of record.  Your father?  Or did your father's friend just take his money and buy them "for him"?

Answer (score 3):

> Is anything possible, and if so, how?

Because of the circumstances, there is **nothing** you can do. You do not have the ISIN, nor are you a part-owner of the account.

The information you would need is:

1. The brokerage (for contacting purposes).
2. ISIN to identify the exact stock/ bond; this number would record the purchase price and the date of purchase (you just have the year which is not enough to find).
3. Your father's account number with permission to access it.

As always, good luck.